# access parents variable in Sweet.js

Tags: javascript, sweet.js

I'm creating a new object orientation system and I need to access the variables of the parent of the macro. I have the following:

```
macro module {
    rule { $i:ident { $e ... } } => {
        var $i = {
            $e ...
        }
    }
}

macro fn {
    rule { $i:ident { $e ... } } => {
        $e ...
    }
}

module x {
    fn name { 

    }
}
```

I want be able to, in `fn macro`, have available the `module` name, in this case, `x`, because maybe I want to do something like `$parentModule.prototype.myFunc`. But if I do `$e$e` it doesn't works properly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this but I think the simplest thing to do is use named [patterns](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#named-patterns):

```
macro module {
    rule { 
        $i:ident {
            $mbody:(fn $name:ident { $body ...}) ...
        }
    } => {
        $i.prototype.$mbody$name ...
    }
}

module x {
    fn name { 

    }
}
```